# How to use yield inside map for React Native

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

My goal is to execute the forked function inside `map`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
  function* doSomethingWithItem(item) {}

  yield all(items.map(item => {
    // ... some item checking
    return fork(doSomethingWithItem, item);
  }));
```

Tried also using `yield fork()` but got an error "yield is a reserved word..."

`doSomethingWithItem()` isn't called.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `map` uses lambda functions, you can't actually yield something from there directly.

`yield all` is a correct approach, but instead of `fork`, `call` effect looks more appropriate in this case because it is blocking, and, therefore, preserves the items processing order (if this matters):

```
function * doSomethingWithItem ( item ) {
  console.log('doSomethingWithItem', item)
}

function * doSomethingWithAllItems ( items ) {
  console.log('doSomethingWithAllItems')
  yield all(items.map(item =>
    call(doSomethingWithItem, item),
  ))
  console.log('done doSomethingWithAllItems')
}

function * mySaga () {
  yield call(doSomethingWithAllItems, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
}
```

I also checked your code, and `doSomethingWithItem` does work in my environment. Try wrapping your code in try/catch, maybe you have an error that makes saga stop.

Comment: yeah, the error was unrelated after `catch`ing the error. thanks~