# map redux saga results

Tags: arrays, redux, redux-saga

**Code**

I followed [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193476/how-to-use-yield-inside-map-for-react-native) to understand how to use the map with the yield.

my code is splitted in 3 parts:

**Example data**

```
citiesCode = [
 {
  bankCityId: A305
  cityId: B544
 },
 {
  bankCityId: R394
  cityId: D873
 },
]
```

1) the function that invoke when i launch the relative action

```
export function* getInvoiceCities({ citiesCode }) {
  yield call(invoiceCities, citiesCode);
}
```

2)this function allow me to map the array that citiesCode is

```
export function* invoiceCities(citiesCode) {
  yield all(citiesCode.map(cityCode => call(getCityInfo, cityCode)));
}
```

3)  in this last function i use the relative code to made a call to the bankCityUrl and cityUrl to obtain the information about the relative city.

```
const citiesInfoList = [];

function* getCityInfo({ bankCity, city }) {
  const cityUrl = `/cities/${city}`;
  const bankCityUrl = `/cities/${bankCity}`;
  try {
    const cityInfoResponse = yield call(fetchWrapper, {
      url: cityUrl,
    });

    const bankCityInfoResponse = yield call(fetchWrapper, {
      url: bankCityUrl,
    });

    citiesInfoList.push(cityInfoResponse, bankCityInfoResponse);
    console.log('cities.info', citiesInfoList);

    // if (cityInfoResponse.status && bankCityInfoResponse.status === 'success') {
    //   yield put(saveInvoiceCitiesResponse(citiesInfoList));
    // }
  } catch ({ packet, response }) {
    if (response.status !== 422) {
      yield put(pushError({ text: 'sendPraticeSectionError' }));
    }
  }
```

**BUG**

The main bug is: If I call multiple time `getInvoiceCities`  save to make this redux call I store the same cities more and more time.

Just to make an example:

citiesInfoList = []

I call it for the first time: I `console.log('cities.info', citiesInfoList);` `citiesInfoList` will be filled with the right results

I call it for the second time: I `console.log('cities.info', citiesInfoList);` `citiesInfoList` will be filled with the right results x 2

I call it for the second time: I `console.log('cities.info', citiesInfoList);` `citiesInfoList` will be filled with the right results x 3

there is a way to avoid this behaviour ? can i stop to store multiple times the same results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found, just some hours ago, an easy answer.

1) i deleted `citiesInfoList = []`  ( it was very ugly to see imho)
2) in the second function i did this

```
export function* invoiceCities(citiesCode) {
  const results = yield all(
    citiesCode.map(cityCode => call(getCityInfo, cityCode)),
  );
  yield put(saveInvoiceCitiesResponse(results));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is happening because all your sagas sits in one file

If I undertood you correctly, when you call an action that invokes `getInvoiceCities`, it will invoke `invoiceCities`, and the later will invoke `getCityInfo` for each `cityCode`.

BUT, since you have defined `const citiesInfoList = [];` in the same module. What happens next is that `getCityInfo` will start using `citiesInfoList` for each `getCityInfo` invocation, resulting in a duplicated results as you have described.

I suggest the following:

1. **Recommended**: Get `citiesInfoList` out of this file to a separate file, and [build a reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) to manage it.
2. Reset `citiesInfoList = []` before every push.